# How to apply patch on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, patch

There is a bug in Eclipse which is already solved on on it's bug tracking web site. Here is the [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426438)

How to apply this patch?

Comment: You need access to the source code and the ability to build eclipse if you want to [apply a patch](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-68c.htm)

Comment: As @DavidPostill said you need access to the source code. After getting access edit the file under a/org.eclipse.debug.ui/ using [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=240328&action=diff#a/org.eclipse.debug.ui/ui/org/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/stringsubstitution/SelectedResourceManager.java_sec3) to apply the patch.